# How to send file content as string in data raw payload using cURL post request

Tags: linux, windows, unix, curl, http-post

Below is my curl query to send the post request

in the "payload" key of the json data i need to send file that is 1 MB of text data as values. Instead of copy past the whole text as string this should take the text as string from locally saved file in my drive.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
            "fileFormat":"csv",
            "version":"v1",
            "payload":"<local file content should come here>",

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your data payload into the file and try with this: `curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/test' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --d @/path/to/filename.json`. Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: This the whole body that we need to send as json right. i need to send the file content as string inside the body of the json. file content as string to be loaded in the payload property
{
            "fileFormat":"csv",
            "version":"v1",
            "payload":"<local file content should come here>",

}

Comment: yep, you can try with that

Comment: found solution from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57809316/6742082